# Duplicate data on multiple inner joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have drawn a simple ERD:

[image]

The query I perform:

```sql
select s.*, count(c.store_id), count(p.store_id)
from store s
inner join customer c on c.store_id = s.id
inner join product p on p.store_id = p.id
group by s.id, s.store_name, s.address
```

The result:

| id | store_name | address | count(c.store_id) | count(p.store_id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | store1 | place | 12 | 12 |
| 2 | store2 | place | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | store3 | place | 29 | 29 |
| 4 | store4 | place | 9 | 9 |

Why do the counts give back the same number?

Every row has the same number for both count functions.

Did I mess up by joining customer and product on the same id field from store?

Comment: You're inner joining your tables, by definition the rows on the inner and outer side of the join must match, both are equivalent to `count(*)`. Simply remove the aggregation and examine the rows in the results and count the non-null values for each column... you won't find any null values. Why are you expecting them to be different, *what* are you counting?

Comment: An ERD is an image of DDL. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) When an image is appropriate: Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Don't use transparency because the site has both black & white background modes. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: You are asking for a store id to equal a product id. After you fix it you may have the problem [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097). But you don't say how the result should be a function of input. So we don't know what query expressions would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use *correlated subqueries* to count:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*) from customer c where c.store_id = s.id),
       (select count(*) from product p  where p.store_id = s.id)
from store s
```

Alternatively, `GROUP BY` in *derived tables* before joining:

```
select s.*, c.c_count, p.p_count
from store s
left join (select store_id, count(*) c_count
           from customer
           group by store_id) c on c.store_id = s.id
left join (select store_id, count(*) p_count
           from product
           group by store_id) p on p.store_id = s.id
```

Answer (score 2):

on the second join, you are joining product with itself `p.store_id = p.id`

Simple data :

```
CREATE TABLE store (
  id int,
  store_name varchar(20),
  address varchar(20)
);

insert into store values
(1,'store1','address1'),
(2,'store2','address2'),
(3,'store3','address3');

CREATE TABLE product (
  product_name int,
  store_id int
);

insert into product values
(1,1),
(2,1);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_name int,
  store_id int
);

insert into customer values
(1,2),
(2,2);
```

Then use `LEFT JOIN`, and `COUNT(DISTINCT ...id)` to eliminate duplicates :

To check if a store has customers/products :

```
select s.*, count(DISTINCT c.store_id), count(DISTINCT p.store_id)
from store s
left join customer c on c.store_id = s.id
left join product p on p.store_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.store_name, s.address
```

Result :

```
id  store_name  address     count(c.store_id)   count(p.store_id)
1   store1      address1    0                   1
2   store2      address2    1                   0
3   store3      address3    0                   0
```

To get number of customers/products per store :

```
select s.*, count(DISTINCT c.customer_name) as number_customers, count(DISTINCT p.product_name) as number_products
from store s
left join customer c on c.store_id = s.id
left join product p on p.store_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.store_name, s.address
```

Result :

```
id  store_name  address     number_customers    number_products
1   store1      address1    0                   2
2   store2      address2    2                   0
3   store3      address3    0                   0
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vEe7fb3H)

Comment: Will not return what OP expects.

Comment: Correct, with `inner join` not working, but with `Left join` is working

Comment: No. For a store with 50 customers and 100 products, the join will produce 50 x 100 = 5000 rows. If you count the IDs, no matter which, you get a count of 5000, because `COUNT(expression)` counts all rows for which the expression is not null. You can solve this with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...id)`, which will work, but this will still produce the huge intermediate result. Better go with jarlh's queries.

Comment: Thats correct @ThorstenKettner, I have edited my answer

Comment: You need to count distinct names, not distinct store_id's. See adjusted fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/IGuKeCSx

Comment: Its depends on what the OP need ! .. I edited my answer to cover two possibilities since the question is not clear !